# HQL to Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I am trying to create a Criteria from HQL.

Simplified HQL:

```
SELECT
    event.pkid,
    add.name
FROM Event event
LEFT JOIN event.addresses adds
JOIN adds.address add
WHERE adds is null
   or adds.addressType = 'EVENT'
```

And I use following Criteria to produce an equivalent query.

```
criteria.createAlias("addresses", "adds",
            CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
            .createAlias("adds.address", "add",
            CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
            .setProjection(
                    Projections
                            .projectionList()
                            .add(Projections.property("pkid"))
                            .add(Projections
                                    .property("add.name")))
            .add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.isNull("addresses"),
                    Restrictions.eq(
                            "adds.addressType.addressType",
                            "EVENT")));
```

But it produces following query,

```
select
    this_.pkid as y0_,
    add2_.name as y1_
from event this_
left outer join event_address_map adds1_ on this_.pkid=adds1_.event_pkid
where (this_.pkid is null or adds1_.address_type=?)
```

Second join is not added. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the SQL produced by the original HQL look like?

Comment: @Richard Neish SQL by HQL: select event0_.pkid as col_0_0_, address2_.name as col_1_0_ from event event0_ left outer join event_address_map addresses1_ on event0_.pkid=addresses1_.event_pkid left outer join address address2_ on addresses1_.address_pkid=address2_.pkid where addresses1_.address_pkid is null or addresses1_.address_type='EVENT'